# A better timeline figure using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, timeline

I want to draw a figure that is as close as possible to the hand drawn figure below.

[image]

I have attempted the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{enumitem}

    \begin{document}
          \begin{figure}
        \setlist[itemize]{nosep, leftmargin=*}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            node distance = 0mm and 0.02\linewidth,
            box/.style = {inner xsep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
                text width=0.32\linewidth,
                align=left, font=\small}
            ]
            \node (n1) [box]
            {   \begin{itemize}
                    \item   Households can produce or consume $x$ with equal probability
                    \item Young entrepreneurs borrow bank deposits to buy $x$ for investment
                    \item Young bankers issue deposits and loans
                \end{itemize}
            };
            \node (n2) [box, below right=of n1.north east]
            {   \begin{itemize}
                    \item  $\frac{1}{4}$ probability of type $l$ consumers
                    \item  $\frac{1}{4}$ probability of type $h$ consumers
                    \item  $\frac{1}{2}$ probability of producers
                \end{itemize}
            };
            \node (n3) [box, below right=of n2.north east]
            {   \begin{itemize}
                    \item   Old entrepreneurs get output, repay loans, consume $x$ and die
                    \item   Old bankers receive loan repayments, consume $x$ and die
                \end{itemize}
            };
            \draw[thick, -latex]    (n1.north west) -- (n3.north east);
            \draw (n1.north) -- + (0,3mm) node[above] {Day};
            \draw (n2.north) -- + (0,3mm) node[above] {Night};
            \draw (n3.north) -- + (0,3mm) node[above] {Day};
        \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

The codes above produce this figure:
[image]

This is different from what I want. I want to include the $t$ and $t+1$ and also have the tick marks cut through the line and they will appear centered on the line if that makes sense? Also, probably would be better getting some chunk of text above the line like they appear on the hand drawn figure.

Comment: The question is much better phrased now. In the future it would be better if you edit your question to improve it instead of deleting it and asking a new one. If you do this repeatedly, you risk that the deleted questions with negative score will cause a question ban.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I just deleted bc it was pretty much a mess before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a PGFKeys-powered approach where `\tikztimeline` expects a list of entries where you can set none or all of the four values `top`, `above`, `below`, `bottom` for each element in the list.

You can use `\tikztimelineset` to adjust default values on a global scale or use the optional argment of `\tikztimeline` to set values only for one diagram.

The lengths `segment width` and `tick length` can be adjusted.

You will make sure that `segment width` × entries won't be too long for your page.

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand*\tikztimelineset{\pgfqkeys{/tikz/timeline}}
\tikztimelineset{
  segment width/.initial=4cm, tick length/.initial=6pt,
  topbot/.style={
    align=flush left,
    text width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/timeline/segment width}
           -2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep})},
  top/.initial=, above/.initial=, below/.initial=, bottom/.initial=}
\newcommand*\tikztimeline[2][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[timeline/every timeline/.try,timeline/.cd,#1]
\foreach[count=\CNT] \elem in {#2}{
  \tikztimelineset{/tikz/style/.expand once=\elem}
  \tikzset{xshift=\CNT*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/timeline/segment width})}
  \unless\ifnum\CNT=1\relax
  \draw (down:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/timeline/tick length}) -- coordinate (lasttick)
        (  up:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/timeline/tick length});
  \fi
  \node[above] (@above) at (right:{.5*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/timeline/segment width})})
    {\strut$\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/timeline/above}$};
  \node[above, timeline/topbot] at (@above.north) {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/timeline/top}};
  \node[below] (@below) at (@above.south) {\strut\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/timeline/below}};
  \node[below, timeline/topbot] at (@below.south) {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/timeline/bottom}};
}
\draw[->] (right:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/timeline/segment width})
      -- ([xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/timeline/segment width}] lasttick);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\tikztimelineset{every timeline/.append style={>=Latex}}

\begin{document}
\tikztimeline{
  {
    top=Households can produce or consume $x$ with equal probabilit.,
    above=t,
    below=Day,
    bottom=Young entrepreneurs borrow bank deposits to buy $x$ for investment.\\
           Young bankers issue deposits and loans.
  }, {
    top=$\frac{1}{4}$ probability of type $l$ consumers.
        $\frac{1}{4}$ probability of type $h$ consumers.
        $\frac{1}{2}$ probability of producers.,
    below=Night
  }, {
    above=t+1,
    below=Day,
    bottom={Old entrepreneurs get output, repay loans, consume $x$ and die.\\
            Old bankers receive loan repayments, consume $x$ and die.}
  }}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]